# How do I redirect a domain but keep the URL structure?

Tags: 7, redirection, .htaccess

I have example.com and example.co.uk. They both point to the same Drupal installation on my server, so both domains load the exact same site.

I am now trying to redirect the .co.uk to the .com domain. I have tried using the following lines in the .htaccess file, but it always redirects to /index.php.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 [P]
```

The following lines didn't work either.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The site redirects. but it doesn't keep the URL structure as it should. If I go to example.co.uk, I get redirected to example.com. If I go to example.co.uk/node/1, I get redirect to example.com/index.

How can I set up the correct redirect?

Answer (score 3):

Your second variant is close to the goal. But it needs some edits. Firstly, you should escape all dots in RewriteCond, so it will be

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
```

Secondly you need to edit RewriteRule to change regular expression and append request uri:

```sh
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It also matters where you place the code. Your second variant is right. It's best to place code just after `RewriteEngine on`

Final code will be:

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```